# How to tell whether a variable has been initialized in C#?

Tags: c#, class, isset

I know this is a dumb question and I guess it must have been asked before. However I am unable to find an answer to my question.

Here is some sample code (which of course does not compile) to outline my problem:

```
class test
{
     int[] val1;
     string val2;

     static bool somefunction(test x, test y)
     {
         dosomestuff()

         test result;

         while(result is nothing)
         {
              if(somecondition){result=new test(something);}
         }
     }
}
```

The problem which I have is in the following line:

```
while(result is nothing)
```

This is the syntax from VB, which of course is not what the C# compiler accepts.
Could somebody tell me how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all.  I ran into a lot of this when I went from VB.NET to C#.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is:

```
while (result == null)
```

You also have to set `result = null;` to start with also

Comment: This will **not work with *value types***. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195597/how-to-tell-whether-a-variable-has-been-initialized-in-c#9726168) below for the fixes.

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the question. The question was asking specifically about a `class` called `test` which is not a value type.

Comment: (Agreed, your answer is correct and complete with respect to the asker's example.  I considered it useful though to point out that it's not complete with respect to the question's more general title;  which to me seems far from obvious, but relevant to other people coming across this question.)

Comment: I declare a class but don't initialize it. then if try to check if( myClass == null ) visual sutdio wont let me run this program at all. Error is "use of unsigned local variable"

Answer (score 39):

- **TL;DR:**

  `if (Object.Equals(`*`myVariable`*`, default(`*`MyVariableType`*`)))`

  - Replace *`myVariable`* and *`MyVariableType`*.

  There are other solutions.

---

`if (myVariable == null)` will **not work**<sup>[1]</sup> **with *[value](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx)***.
(See further below for short intros to  *reference types* vs. *value types*   and `struct`s.)

The value types mainly are `struct`s (e.g. `DateTime`), including<sup>[2]</sup> the [simple types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like `int`, and `enum`erations. Value types don't support a `null` value (intrinsically).

The exception and the fix to this are [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) types: Essentially these add `null` to the possible values of a struct type. They are structurally the same as the `Maybe<T>` you might know from other languages<sup>[3]</sup>. You create them with `ValueType?` (e.g. `int?`) which is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<ValueType>`.

Alternatively, instead of using a nullable type, you could compare your variable to its type's default value:

```
if (Object.Equals(myVariable, default(MyVariableType)))
```

(This will work both for reference types (objects) and value types.)
Note that you have to replace *`MyVariableType`* manually – unfortunately you can **not** do

```
if (Object.Equals(myVariable, default(myVariable.GetType())))
```

because `default()` only accepts a type name directly.  (I suppose it evaluates at compile-time.)

### *structs* in a nutshell

> Put simply, structs are cut-down classes.  Imagine classes that don’t
> support inheritance or finalizers, and you have the cut-down version:
> the struct.  Structs are defined in the same way as classes (except
> with the `struct` keyword), and apart from the limitations just
> described, structs can have the same rich members, including fields,
> methods, properties and operators.
>
> <sub>[Cited from: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx ]</sub>

Classes are *reference types*: A class variable (or more specifically, its memory area) only contains a pointer to an other memory area, where the actual object instance data is stored.

*Value type* variables directly contain the data. This may yield a speed benefit due to [cache locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and saving the lookup. But it may also be detrimental to performance in the case of more complex structs.

---

Footnotes:

[1] It does not even throw an error. `myVariable == null` will always just yield `false`, because your `myVariable` will be initialized with the non-`null` [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) value (zero ([equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)) or a struct of zeros and `null`s). This default value is available with `default(Type)`.

[2] Technically the simple types (all [built-in types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs7y5x0x%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) except `string` and `object`) [are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) structs. Side note: The built-in types are [aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) for types from the [System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx) namespace.

[3] E.g. [in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html). In C# `Maybe<T>` is not built-in, but can be implemented. It provides `Nothing` as a more explicit/self-documenting version of `null` both for classes and structs.

[4] There is no <sup>[4]</sup>. No really, you can go and check.

Comment: Great hint with the ? ValueType.

Answer (score 4):

```
while (result == null)
```

Comment: The compiler throws the following exception for that:
"Use of the unassigned local variable 'test'"

Comment: No, since I did not as Colin Mackay suggested set test=null in the first place.

Comment: OK.  Glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (result ==null )
```

if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Although you have an answer you're happy with, there's something behind this you may find interesting or helpful.

There is a difference between C# and VB.NET. In VB.NET you can write:

```
Dim b as Boolean
```

And in C# you can write:

```
bool b;
```

They are subtly different. In VB.NET, `b` has been given the value false (in other words, it has already been initialized). In C#, `b` has no value (it is uninitialized). C# goes to a lot of effort to make sure you cannot examine the value of a variable that has never been initialized.

So you are not testing whether the variable is initialized. In VB.NET there is no such thing as an uninitialized variable. In C# it is impossible to get the value of an uninitialized variable in order to compare it with anything.

You're testing whether the variable has been initialized to `null` or `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(result == null)
```

The equivalent of nothing in C# is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (result == null)
```